# Longest sequence of 1s in a binary matrix

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, matrices, divide-and-conquer

I would like a hint for this homework question. The problem is to come up with a divide and conquer solution for finding the maximum sequence of 1s in a given a binary matrix of order $n$. The sequences can only happen horizontally or vertically. I know the naive solution for this that consists of going through the rows and columns of the matrix and checking their sum, which is $O(n^2)$. I understand that if $n$ is a power of 2 I could divide the problem in 4 sub-problems and apply the naive solution, but I don't see how this approach can be more efficient (than the naive solution). For example, checking if the sequence goes through the intersection of the sub-matrices or if $n$ is not a power of two, seems that makes this divide and conquer approach less efficient than the naive solution.

Comment: Can you share the original problem text, not paraphrased?

Comment: I wouldn’t be sure what a maximum sequence in a matrix is supposed to be.